# Exception while connecting kafka server through Pepperbox sampler in jmeter

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, jmeter, kafka-producer-api

I am using pepprBox Sample in JMeter to connect kafka server and sending messages on topic.
Application team shared two JKS certificate along with password to connect Kafka server.
For this, I have enabled keystore property in system.properties file:
`javax.net.ssl.keystore=`
`javax.net.ssl.keystorepassword=`

and index entry in jmeter.properties

`https.keystoreStartIndex=0`

`https.keystoreEndIndex=1`

I specified Broker , Zookeeper and Topic name with "SSL"security protocol.
But not able to connect kafka server and getting below exception
--Error While calling watcher
--Java.net.connectException: connection Refused

Please share your best help to correct me if i am doing anything incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PepperBox Kafka Sampler](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) doesn't respect [JMeter System Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter), you need to perform the SSL configuration in the Sampler itself:

[image]

Check out [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) article for more information if needed

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for workaround. I tried to build new jar but due to my organization network restrictions, i am not able to build new jar correctly. Is it possible for you to share your jar  file? Thanks in Advance!